# How do I show the current/live UK (time) using Javascript on my website

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I have a script that I use to display and update the data/time live on a website. So I'll like the display the UK time that also updates when the time passes by not just as a static value.

I'd like it to display the time in a specific timezone (UK) always - is that possible?

I don't need the month in this version, so that's what you can see commented out.

As an aside, even on the original version. The time 'jumps' into view as it takes a while to load - is there away to fix this?

Might be worth noting this is a simple static website, so no database or much else to play with to get the time.

Cheers!

```js
function showDateTime() {
    var currentDate = document.getElementById("date");
    var currentTime = document.getElementById("time");
    
    var date = new Date();
    var dayList = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    /* var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]; */
    var dayName = dayList[date.getDay()];
    /* var monthName = monthNames[date.getMonth()]; */
    /* var today = `${dayName} ${date.getDate()} ${monthName}`; */
    var today = `${dayName}`;
    
    var hour = ('0' + date.getHours()).substr(-2);
    var min = ('0' + date.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
    var sec = ('0' + date.getSeconds()).substr(-2);
    
    
    var time = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    currentDate.innerText = `${today}`;
    currentTime.innerText = `${time}`;
}
setInterval(showDateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<p><span id="date" class="os-menu__item"></span> <span id="time"></span> GMT</p>
```

Comment: `showDateTime(); setInterval(showDateTime, 1000);` will fix the delay

Comment: I don't think the post someone has linked to causing this post to be closed has solved the issue. My code currently updates the time live whereas the linked examples seem to just display it once on load and don't update?

Comment: Yeah my bad, apologies!

Comment: GMT or UTC? Or some country's timezone that uses GMT in winter and some other timezone in summer?

Comment: It would be UK (GMT) as it's to show where I'm based and the current live time as I worked with US clients. But yeah that is annoying, the time changes by an hour in October for example!

Comment: So you want to display the time in Europe/London timezone.

Comment: I updated your question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UK needs INTL - this code will show BST/GMT depending on summertime

```js
const todaySpan = document.getElementById("date");
const opts = {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  weekday: 'short',
  timeZone: 'Europe/London',
  hour12: true, // set to false to get 24 hour format without am/pm
  timeZoneName: 'short'
};

const showDateTime = () => todaySpan.textContent = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', opts);
showDateTime();
setInterval(showDateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<p><span id="date" class="os-menu__item"></span></p>
```

GMT/UTC can be done with string manipulation but will be in 24 hour format

```js
const todaySpan = document.getElementById("date");
const re = /([a-zA-Z]+), (\d+) ([a-zA-Z]+) (\d+) ([\d:]+) (\w+)/;
const showDateTime = () => {
  const [_, dayString, date, month, year, time, tz] = new Date().toUTCString().match(re); // toUTCString is GMT
  todaySpan.textContent =  `${dayString} ${time} ${tz}`.replace(/,/g,""); // remove the comma
};  
showDateTime();
setInterval(showDateTime, 1000);
```

```html
<p><span id="date" class="os-menu__item"></span></p>
```

Comment: Or `new Date().toLocaleString('en',{hour:'2-digit',minute:'2-digit',second:'2-digit', weekday:'short', timeZone:'UTC', hour12: false, timeZoneNameL:'short'})`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG thanks, missed that. However GMT and `timeZoneName:'shortGeneric'` works better

Comment: Yeah thanks both, just looking at this now. My time is showing as 1 hour behind the current time ...I guess that's down to 'day light savings' and how the time changes by 1 hour twice a year?

Comment: That is possible. What is your actual timezone?

Comment: It's UK, so currently GMT+1 I think ...then goes back to GMT in October. Maybe I should've just put UTC haha ...but I guess that does the same thing!

Comment: See update. I changed to timezone Europe/London

Comment: Since your users are in the US, I changed to 12 hour format too

Comment: Nice! That's great @mplungjan thanks a lot. It's not vital but if I wanted to remove the comma from after the weekday (example: "Wed,") is that possible?

Comment: Ah nice, I was just about to post saying I'd added `.replace(',','');` onto the end and it seemed to work on the first example - but I'll use yours as I imagine there's a flaw in mine haha

Comment: No, yours is fine for this example where there is only one comma.

Comment: @mplungjan—beware the vagaries of *Intl*. For Australia/Brisbane, Safari returns "Brisbane Time", which is pretty useless even by civil timezone naming standards (I think the US has at least 11 towns named Brisbane, not to mention other countries). It should be either EST (common before globalisation) or AEST (more common recently). Other variants have been used from time to time…